# Django, Mezzanine: Autodiscover error, referencing non-existent model

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

The Django project I'm working on was set up by someone else, prior to me working on it. It has also the Mezzanine component which I'm not familiar with; have not been needing to use it. Suddenly, I have an error which I can't figure out how to fix...

I have an app 'Dashboards' which started off without any models -- models.py was empty, sans the default `from django.db import models`. Today, I added a model called `Banners` into it, and I added the admin.py file (as I was intending to use Django's admin module for it). I may have  restarted foreman throughout but I *never* ran any migrations on the model.

Subsequently, I decided to delete the model definitions as well as admin.py, because I decided to create a separate app to handle the specific feature I was working on. After restarting foreman, Django keeps throwing an error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named banners.models
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Django Version: 1.5.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named banners.models
Exception Location: /home/vagrant/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /home/vagrant/www/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['.',
 '',
 '/home/vagrant/www/src/django-experiments',
 '/home/vagrant/www/src/gargoyle',
 '/home/vagrant/www/src/nexus',
 '/home/vagrant/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.6.0.5/newrelic/bootstrap',
 '/home/vagrant/www/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/vagrant/www/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/vagrant/www/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/vagrant/www/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/vagrant/www/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/vagrant/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 18 Feb 2014 01:13:55 +0000
```

More specifically, in:

```
./urls.py in <module>
admin.autodiscover() ...
▶ Local vars
/home/vagrant/www/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/boot/__init__.py in autodiscover
    django_autodiscover(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
```

I searched all my source, definitely I'm NOT importing 'banners' anywhere. What is the proper way to completely clear it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are definitely not importing banners anywhere (a search through your codebase should confirm this), then you may have compiled python files still referencing the old stuff.

I can't reproduce exactly what causes this, but I've run into problems like this many times, specifically manifesting in cryptic urls.py import errors.

Try a good old `find . -name "*.pyc" | xargs rm`

As usual, be very careful with `rm` commands - never trust it, triple check you wrote *.pyc or have backups / version control.

Comment: Aha, so we delete all compiled python files from the project's folder to remove any residual references. Fixed, thanks!!